# "OverflowError: date value out of range" using suds-jurko in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, xml, soap, suds

I am using suds-jurko to make soap calls, and I've hit a bit of a snag. I have a number of calls working, but one of my calls fails with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soap.py", line 160, in <module>
    result = client.service.QueryCachePointDetails(cachepoint)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 521, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 581, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 621, in send
    original_soapenv=original_soapenv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 685, in process_repl
y
    self.method, replyroot)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 147, in ge
t_reply
    return self.unmarshaller().process(nodes[0], resolved)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\typed.py", line 66, in process
    return Core.process(self, content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 46, in process
    return self.append(content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 61, in append
    self.append_children(content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 138, in append_chi
ldren
    cval = self.append(cont)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 61, in append
    self.append_children(content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 138, in append_chi
ldren
    cval = self.append(cont)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 61, in append
    self.append_children(content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 138, in append_chi
ldren
    cval = self.append(cont)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\core.py", line 62, in append
    self.append_text(content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\typed.py", line 133, in append_te
xt
    content.text = self.translated(content.text, known)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\umx\typed.py", line 139, in translate
d
    return resolved.translate(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\xsd\sxbuiltin.py", line 162, in trans
late
    return DateTime(value).value
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\sax\date.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.value = self.__parse(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\sax\date.py", line 151, in __parse
    value += datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1)
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

I believe the last part is key, because the XML includes this gem:

```
<LastStatusUpdateTime>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</LastStatusUpdateTime>
```

Which it chokes on, and spits out that error.

So my questions are thus: Can I drop this specific part of the XML using suds-jurko? Is this a problem with suds-jurko or a problem with that XML response?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this with MessagePlugin:

```
class TimePlugin(MessagePlugin):
  def received(self, context):
        search = context.reply.replace('9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999', '')
        context.reply = search
```

Then I called it later with:

```
client = Client(url, plugins=[TimePlugin()])
```

I believe the issue is that suds-jurko dies trying to add a microsecond to this time, but it was easy enough to just change the time to something else. It only occurs here, and only can happen in a specific circumstance so this fix will work for now.

I may ultimately just reduce the time so it can add a microsecond as normal, but only because I want it to show up as this same time for output reasons.